# Objective-C: #import "ALAssetsLibrary.h" - file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

actually, I am running into this issue and I cannot figure out why:
I try to use `ALAssetsLibrary` which is part of the `AssetsLibrary.framework`

In my `ViewController.m` I place this import statement

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ALAssetsLibrary.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


}

@end
```

But xcode (version 6) gives me **'ALAssetsLibrary.h' file not found**.

So this is what I checked to solve this so far:

1. Go to my target, go to Build Phases, section Link Binary With Libraries --> Here I have added the AssetsLibrary.framework

I have no clue, what I have overseen, hoping somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Cheers, John

Comment: you should import in this way `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` OR  `#import <AssetsLibrary/ALAssetsLibrary.h>`

Comment: Oh brilliant. Works like a charm! New things learned! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Use this

`#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>`